# About the sequence $n^{\frac{1}{n}} -1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am having trouble with this multiple-select mcq question:

> The value of $n^{\frac{1}{n}} -1$
>
> 1. tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$,
> 2. is greater than $\frac{\log n}{n}$ for all $n\geq 3$,
> 3. is greater than $\log n$ for all $n\geq 3$,
> 4. is greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n\geq 3$.

I know that option 1 is correct, because $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}} =1$.

Also,

$$n^{\frac{1}{n}} -1=-1+ e^{\frac{\log n}{n}} =\frac{\log n}{n} + \frac{(\log n)^2}{n^2}/2! +...\geq \frac{\log n}{n},$$ meaning option 2 is also correct.

But I don't see how to prove or disprove the other two options.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try finding one $n$ for which it is untrue (for which it is false).

Comment: For 3. note that $\log n$ goes to $\infty$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @MarsPlastic missed that! But what about option 4?

Comment: For 3, $3^{1/3}-1 < 1 < \log{3}$. For 4., show that $n^{1/n}-1 \leq \frac{\log(n)}{n}+(e-2)\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}.$

Comment: For 4 you can just plug in n=4: $$\sqrt{2}-1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using the binomial theorem,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \left(1+\sqrt{\frac2n}\right)^n
   &\ge1\color{#AAA}{+n\sqrt{\frac2n}}+\frac{n(n-1)}2\frac2n\color{#AAA}{+\cdots}\\
   &\ge n\color{#AAA}{+\sqrt{2n}+\cdots}
   \end{align}
   $$
   Therefore, $1\le n^{1/n}\le1+\sqrt{\frac2n}$. thus,
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)=0
   $$

   ---
2. Using the Taylor series for $e^x$,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   n^{1/n}
   &=e^{\log(n)/n}\\
   &=1+\frac{\log(n)}n+\frac12\left(\frac{\log(n)}n\right)^2+\frac16\left(\frac{\log(n)}n\right)^3+\cdots
   \end{align}
   $$
   Therefore,
   $$
   n^{1/n}-1\ge\frac{\log(n)}n
   $$

   ---
3. Since 1. is true, 3 cannot be.

   ---
4. Bernoulli's Inequality says $\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\ge2$. Because $\frac{\log(x)}x$ is decreasing for $x\gt e$, for $n\ge16$, $\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\le\frac{\log(2)}2$; that is, $n\le2^{\sqrt{n}}$. Thus,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   n^{1/n}
   &\le2^{1/\sqrt{n}}\\
   &\le1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
   \end{align}
   $$
   Therefore, for $n\ge16$,
   $$
   n^{1/n}-1\le\frac1{\sqrt{n}}
   $$

Answer (score 2):

To tackle the fourth question, you can let

$$f(x)=x^\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

For $x^\frac{1}{x}$, it is easy to show that it is increasing by looking at its derivative, so the function $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is increasing. Then what you need to do is to check the case where $n=3$.